# Android Studio, React Native, Gradle: Project Sometimes Builds But Won't Run due to Ambiguous Errors & Warnings

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

**INTRO**

This is a mobile project I've wanted to have running in Android Studio for over a month now.  (It also uses React Native and Gradle as major components.)  As previously mentioned elsewhere, I inherited this private code base from others who worked on this project who have generally been non communicative with me and unhelpful regarding fixing this code.  (I'm still under NDA about certain things, meaning I can't safely share this code base with you.)

The relevant info listed below.

**SOME THINGS I HAVE TRIED**

-Starting over from the base version of the code and installing all relevant Node Modules via Yarn and NPM.  (I know it's best to use only one package manager, but the other people on this project used a variety of package managers, and even using only one package manager seemingly has the same effect.  I have also used NPM Audit Fix for things downloaded and installed via NPM.)

-Asking for help elsewhere.  StackOverflow has been a reliable source of help, whereas asking on FreeCodeCamp, Reddit, and certain other places yielded no replies.

-Experimenting with the code.  Reading the code comments and changing values in a controlled environment hasn't helped enough.

-Research.  Checking StackOverflow and other places and changing bits of code to seemingly improve it hasn't helped enough.

**TECH USED**

-Windows 10 Home 64-Bit Edition

-Android Studio 4.0.1

-React Native

-Node.JS

-Gradle: Version 6.0.1 is installed globally, but Gradle 7 may have overridden it in this project as part of an automatic update.

**DESIRED CODE BEHAVIOR**

Primarily and very preferably:  The code runs.

Secondarily:  The code doesn't run but displays easily-understandable and easily-fixable errors.

**ANDROID STUDIO WARNINGS AND COMMENTARY**

This is with compile statements in the code instead of api or implementation statements.

```
The following project options are deprecated and have been removed:
```

(The warning ends after this, showing *nothing* of what was deprecated!)

```
Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
```

(Thanks, I think.  Mass replacing 'compile' to 'api' results in a readout described below.)

**ANDROID STUDIO MESSAGE LOG - ERRORS, WARNINGS, DEBUG MESSAGES, ETC.. - WITH COMPILE INSTEAD OF API**

Linked due to length.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mWprISb_XL-Q-2pKl9qKGK7BIi5ftyjQyP9XFyRNqbo/edit?usp=sharing

**ANDROID STUDIO MESSAGE LOG - ERRORS, WARNINGS, DEBUG MESSAGES, ETC.. - AFTER REPLACING COMPILE WITH API**

Linked due to length.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SPi86a0KHIOCiKjK2WBU0ydsBSG3Nwzu1E7GqrZw6tk/edit?usp=sharing )

**FINALLY FOR NOW**

Thankee for your aid.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding `compile` warning as Android deprecated, now we should use `implementation` and this warning come due to some `npm module` still using `compile` keyword.  need to be updated with `implementation` in gradle file.

some time App build fail due gradle cache. After clearing this, App will run successfully.

```
To clear gradle cache go to android folder run 

For mac
./gradlew clean
For Window
gradlew clean
```

Comment: I followed your cleaning advice and received the same error messages after changing compile to implementation or compile to api.  What else do you advise?

Comment: @GregCampbell could you please show your exact error ?